# Is it necessary to give each Widget (TextView, LinearLayout...) an Id?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-layout

I mean widgets that are not going to be touched through program code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The id used to access widgets from code. If you don't need that, you don't need an ID.

Comment: There is one special case where you may need to add an id to a view that is not referenced from code. If you are using RelativeLayouts the ids will be used to identify views to define layout_above or layout_alignBaseline etc.